# Clarifications involving automorphisms of projective planes and lines?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry

I have been learning some classical projective geometry recently and I am hoping to gain some clarity regarding various different automorphism groups.  There are three different levels of generality that I am interested in and for now I will draw a distinction between them.  The most general object of interest is a (synthetic) projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ (which is a set, the "points", together with a collection of subsets, the "lines", that satisfies the condition that every pair of distinct points lie on a unique line and dually every pair of distinct lines intersects in a unique point, together with some nondegeneracy conditions).  Within the class of projective planes, there are some nice ones which are constructed using coordinates, namely the projective planes $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$ where $D$ is a division algebra.  Within this class are the even nicer projective planes constructed from fields $\mathbb{P}^2(F)$.

Before getting to my questions, let me just set up a little (I believe) standard terminology.  Given a point $P \in \mathbb{P}^2$ not lying on a line $l \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, then there is a bijection between the pencil of lines through $P$ (i.e., the set of all lines through $P$) and the set of points on $l$ just given by intersections.  The composition of two such bijections (so it is a map either between two pencils or two lines) is called a perspectivity.  The composition of multiple perspectivities is called a projectivity.

For an arbitrary projective plane, we have two groups I want to consider.  The first is the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^2$, $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2)$, is just the set of all bijections $\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ that preserve the lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$.  The second is the so-called group of projective collineations, $\text{PC}(\mathbb{P}^2)$, which are automorphisms $\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ that when restricted to any line are a projectivity onto their image line.

In the case where the projective plane comes with coordinates, $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$, there is a further group $\text{PGL}_3(D)$ which acts on $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$.

Furthermore, given a line $l \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ there is the group $\text{PJ}(l)$ of self-projectivities from $l$ to $l$.  When we have coordinates, say in $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$ and we choose say $[x,y,z]$ and we let $l$ be the line $z=0$ then we have the group $\text{PGL}_2(D)$ acting on $l$ by projectivities.  Further, we can define the cross-product of 4 points in $l$ and we have the group $R_\times(\mathbb{P}^2(D))$ of bijections $\mathbb{P}^2(D) \to \mathbb{P}^2(D)$ that preserve the cross-ratio.

Here are some things that I know to be true:

(a) In the case of a field, we have $\text{PGL}_3(F) \cong \text{PC}(\mathbb{P}^2(F))$ (this maybe justifies considering $\text{PC}(\mathbb{P}^2(F))$ as it is a synthetic analog of an analytically natural object).

(b) In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, we have $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})) \cong \text{PGL}_3(\mathbb{R})$.

(c) In the case of a field, $\text{PGL}_2(F) \cong \text{PJ}(l) = R_\times(\mathbb{P}^2(F))$.

Questions:

(1) To what extent does (a) extend to projective planes of the form $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$?

(2) To what extent does (b) extend to projective planes of the form $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$ or maybe more specifically $\mathbb{P}^2(F)$? How do $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{D}))$ and  $\text{PGL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ in general differ?

(3) To what extent does (b) extend to projective planes of the form $\mathbb{P}^2(D)$ or maybe more specifically $\mathbb{P}^2(F)$?

Thanks for the help! Any references are also welcome!